# How to find out which directives were applied to an element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, angularjs-directive

**Is there a way to find out, for any given element, which AngularJS directives were applied on it/its attributes?**

In a large web application, I am looking at an HTML element that has an additional attribute that I suspect might invoke a directive (the attribute name is obviously specific to our application). Or it might simply be dead code.

It looks something like this:

```
<button ctl-remember-special data-ng-click="handleAction()"></button>
```

(`ctl-remember-special` being the possible directive in this example)

I cannot seem to find a directive of the appropriate name in our project, but I am not entirely sure because some of the identifiers in our application are assembled at runtime. (To provide an impression of the dimensions, I am seeing more than 6000 directive definitions in our code.)

Comment: `angular.element(document.body).injector().has(name+"Directive")` will check if directive exists. Whereas to check if it was used (applied as an attribute) is a lot harder. You can dig in rendered HTML (post-compilation) with `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` (as an example for just `<div>` tags) and for each element check its `attributes` field. Stuff like `ng-view` will appear there. Except that directives can be used differently: `<my-directive>` / `<div my-directive>` / `<div class="my-directive">`, so that makes it a lot harder to work with